# Unrequired field error w/ Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using the Django REST Framework to run CRUD processes on my database/Django models. My model for storing client data is pretty simple, and only one field is causing me problems: a CharField for storing either a custom or auto-generated string.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=254, default=link_generator())
```

I make a POST request to the `/clients/` endpoint with form input - if a user enters a custom string via the input, it stores that string as expected. If they leave this field blank, that's fine - I want to run my link_generator function, which creates a random string (code below). **Instead I get an error - the Django REST Framework GUI tells me, "This field may not be blank."** But nowhere do I specify that it should be required. If I inspect the serializer, it explicitly says it's not required:

```
>>> from landing.serializers import ClientSerializer
>>> serializer = ClientSerializer()
>>> print(serializer)

ClientSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    email = EmailField(max_length=254, required=False)
    notes = CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False, style={'type': 'textarea'})
    link = CharField(max_length=254, required=False)
    link_expired = BooleanField(required=False)
    created = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    updated = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
```

UPDATE: Adding the serializer code w/ suggested improvement - pretty basic:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'notes', 'link', 'link_expired', 'created', 'updated')
        extra_kwargs = {
        'link': {
            'required': False,
         }
    }
```

[Still, upon submitting I get this error every time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hUCm.jpg) What makes it think that field is required? Again, I want to allow the user to leave this field blank, and run the link_generator function if they do. If I expressly say `blank=True` as below:

```
link = CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, default=link_generator())
```

...the link_generator doesn't run and a blank string ends up being stored. For what it's worth, here's the link_generator code I want to run in the event the user leaves the input blank (sidenote: I declared this above the model - is that bad practice? Where should it be declared):

```
def link_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

Any insights out there? I'm stumped - just don't see why it should be getting flagged like that. I'm relatively new to Django and REST in general - thanks for any help.

Comment: can you update your post and include your ClientSerializer() from your serializers.py file? I know you printed out the serializer but just in case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @user2719875, I figured out the solution. To get the desired behavior - allowing the user to enter a custom string, defaulting to a string generator function if no input is given - I needed to define the default in the serializer itself, not the model. Using the `extra_kwargs` to select the desired 'link' field, I declare the default function here:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'notes', 'link', 'link_expired', 'created', 'updated')
    extra_kwargs = {
        'link': {
            'default': link_generator
         }
    }
```

Interestingly, it looks for the link_generator function in models.py itself, so the code is stored there, above the model. Not sure if this is the best practice, but it works. Removed the `default=link_generator` from the model itself as below:

```
def link_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    link_expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # added only on creation
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  # updates each time the object is saved
```

Working great. Thanks for the help, all!

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your serializer to this:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'notes', 'link', 'link_expired', 'created', 'updated')
        extra_kwargs = {
                'link': {
                    # Tell DRF that the link field is not required.
                    'required': False,
                    'allow_blank': True,
                 }
            }
```

I'm actually surprised that when you print your serializer, DRF says that the `link` field is not required because according to your model, it should be required (because `blank=True` is not set).

Edit: `allow_blank` is what is used for the CharField serializer fields (If set to `True` then the empty string should be considered a valid value). Taken from the DRF documentation here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield

Comment: Huh... I tried this and no luck, same results. If I set the model to `blank=True`, it stores a blank string every time instead of storing the return value of the link_generator function. Not sure what's up... Any other ideas?

Comment: @jckstl Wait, did you try the above code Without setting `blank=True`? Don't set `blank=True` on your model and try making your serializer what I have above. What error does it give when you use the serializer I have above Without setting `blank=True` on your model?

Comment: Tried it both ways, same result:

`{
    "link": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ]
}`

Comment: @jckstl See my update (I added `allow_blank: True` to the `extra_kwargs`). Does it still give the same error even after setting `allow_blank`?

Comment: Okay - this at least allows the Client to be created, but it still stores a blank string instead of storing the link_generator value... Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: @jckstl I believe the reason for this is because when the end-user does not type anything into the `link` field, DRF sends it to the back-end as an empty string, and Django then sees the empty string as a value and therefore uses it to override the default value. I think the question now is, how do we get Django to interpret empty strings as `None` and use the default value when an empty string is provided. Maybe asking that in a new question would be good, because I'm not too sure what the answer is.

Comment: Yeah, probably getting a little off-topic - one more question. I think you're right about it seeing the empty string as a valid value. I think I need to change the API view post method for client creation. I'm able to log my request data with `logging.warning(request.data)` which displays the following object notation: `{'name': 'Test name', 'email': test@email.com', 'link': '', 'notes': ''}` ... I just need to run a check on that data like... `if 'link' == '': 'link' = link_generator` before saving the Client... I'm just not sure get access/change that value in the object notation - any idea?

Comment: @lckstl Well before we get into figuring out how to access link_generator in your serializer, how about trying `if 'link' == '': 'link' = None` (that way, DRF sends None to the backend and Django sees none and uses link_generator to use the default value? Does that work?).

Comment: Figured it out! Instead of defining the default value in the model, I can define it in the serializer, also within the extra_kwargs you suggested earlier - instead of `allow_blank`, I just changed to `extra_kwargs = {
            'link': {
                'default': link_generator
             }
        }` Working great! Thanks for the help! I saw those extra serializer arguments in the DRF documentation but wasn't sure how to add them when defining the serializer through `fields`. I'm pumped - thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem from the first glance that I can see in your code is in default option. It should be function itself(without brackets). Change it to something like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=254, default=link_generator)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is not the cause of his error, but it is indeed a bug in his code.

Comment: @spectras, I would actually recommend author to test it... I think I had problem like this before.

Comment: Thanks, all. I'd actually tried it both ways, w/ and w/o brackets, but thanks for explaining the correct way... Still working on it!

Comment: Correct way is without, because you want to give the function to the field. If you put parenthesises, the function is called once when your serializer is imported, and the field gets the resulting string as default (ergo default will always be that same string that was generated at import time).

Answer (score 0):

My code is

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    users = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

> when executed: for, users='' , getting serializer error required
>   field.
>
> Here required=False & blank=True not working,

I want to allow also blank values..